# How to call a method outside a closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm trying to use the NodeJS module "pcsc-lite" to communicate with a card reader. If you want to take a look at the module : https://github.com/santigimeno/node-pcsclite.

I'm looking for a way to send a sequence of data to my reader using my own method. Because, the module is event-based. So I have to declare two listeners (one in the other) to be able to call the send method.

For example :

```
module.on("reader", function(reader){
    //...
    reader.on("status", function(status){
         //...
         reader.connect({ share_mode : this.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED },function(err, protocol) {

              //This is the method I want to be able to call "when I need it"
              reader.transmit(...);
         });
    });
});
```

I would like to call the transmit method like this for example :

```
function send(...){
     reader.transmit(...);
}
```

I think there is a way to do it, but I seem to be a little bit hooked to my C/Java programming habits.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the closure but the callback functions. You get the reader object only in the callback function. Can you tell your use case when you want to call the `reader.transmit()`

Comment: I would like to create a little API. In deed, the aim is to instantiate a new object such as `myObj` and be able to call `myObj.send(params)` in a loop for example

Comment: But you are not sure when will your `reader` be ready to be called `transmit` method on the same. I would suggest to utilise promises for the same.

Comment: Yes, I already try to use a pomise pattern for the "reader" event, and it works. But I'm a bit confused when I need to use, well let's say, promise in another promise. It's the case if I need to utilise promise for the "status" event.

Comment: I still have doubt if promises are going to solve your purpose.. since these are event subscriptions..

Comment: Do you know another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If your reader will be a singleton, you can declare it outside the callback, and then assign the variable when you're ready. Without knowing more, here's a simple example:

```
let reader; // we prepare a variable that's outside of scope of it all.
// your `send` function
function send(params) {

    let stuff = doStuffWithParams(params);
    reader.transmit(stuff, callback);
}

// we take out init stuff too
function initialize() {

  // we know reader variable is already initialized.
  reader.on('status', function() { 
    reader.connect({
      share_mode : this.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED
    },function(err, protocol) {

      // send.
      send();
      // or even better, emit some event or call some callback from here, to let somebody outside this module know you're ready, then they can call your `send` method.
    });
  });
}    

// now your module init section
let pcsc = require('pcsclite')();
pcsc.on('reader', function(r) {

  // assign it to our global reader
  reader = r;
  initialize();
});
```

Note: don't call your variables `module`, it's refering to the file being currently executed and you can get unexpected behavior.